# update variable in iframe without reloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have an app built with phonegap, that I want to be able to send messages to (e.g, special offer, service announcement etc).

Id like to be able to send the message, if possible, without using push notifications (in case the user hasn't agreed to the app sending them notifications)

is this at all possible? I was thinking something like an iframe (invisible) in the app, which loads content/js from a page I host. If the app simply loops a function to check a variable from within the iframe, something like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(updateMessage == true){
        // code here to grab the message (probably a reload will be needed now?)
    }
})
```

to avoid constantly ajaxing/ reloading the iframe in the background.
Is there a way I can update the variable in the hosted file, and have the app recognise when it has changed without reloading the iframe constantly? (for speed and data usage purposes)

Comment: Take a look at different solutions to avoid excessive reloads here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology If you cannot do a full push, long polling might work.

Comment: thanks, does long polling consume data until a response is sent? or only for the initial send and then for the receive?

Comment: It's just waiting at the server end for data for a long time, not causing you extra dataload. You could think of it as a very slow request.